# Help in finding Jacobian

Tags: calculus, transformation

I have
$$\begin{aligned}x_{1}&=r\sin(\theta_{1}),\\
 x_{2}&=r\cos(\theta_{1})\sin(\theta_{2})\\
x_{3}&=r\cos(\theta_{1})\cos(\theta_{2}).
\end{aligned}
$$
I know how to compute the Jacobian $$\frac{\partial(x_{1},x_{2},x_3)}{\partial(\theta_{1},\theta_{2},r)}$$ directly.

The thing is, there is a way to get this Jacobian that involves a ratio of an upper triangular determinant and a lower triangular determinant. I just cannot figure out how to get this. I'm guessing it's some chain rule thing. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use $\TeX$ on this site by enclosing formulas in dollar signs; single dollar signs for inline formulas and double dollar signs for displayed equations. You can see the source code for any math formatting you see on this site by right-clicking on it and selecting "Show Math As:TeX Commands". [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a basic tutorial and quick reference. There's an "edit" link under the question.

Comment: It is the determinant of a 3 by 3 matrix of partial derivatives of variables $(x, y, z)$ with respect to the other variables $(r, \theta_1, \theta_2)$. I get $r^2\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)^2$.

Comment: That's what I got too - the thing is, the actual problem is for $x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}$ - that's why that trick I was talking about would be very useful

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\partial(\theta_1,\theta_2,r)}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial\theta_1} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial\theta_2} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial\theta_1} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial\theta_2} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial\theta_1} & \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial\theta_2} & \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial r}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
r\cos\theta_1 & 0 & \sin\theta_1 \\
-r\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 & r\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 & \cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2 \\
-r\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2 & -r\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2 & \cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=r^2(\cos^3\theta_1\cos^2\theta_2+\cos^3\theta_1\sin^2\theta_2+\sin^2\theta_1\cos\theta_1\sin^2\theta_2+\sin^2\theta_1\cos\theta_1\cos^2\theta_2)$$
$$=r^2(\sin^2\theta_1+\cos^2\theta_1)(\sin^2\theta_2+\cos^2\theta_2)(4\cos\theta_1)$$
$$=4r^2\cos\theta_1$$